# Encfs unmounted drive is still visible

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unmount, encfs

So I used this:

```
encfs ~/secret ~/plaintext
```

Then I wrote some text files to `plaintext` directory. Then I unmounted by doing this:

```
fusermount -u ~/plaintext
```

Yet when I go to the `/secret/` directory I can still see the encrypted drive mounted and the data inside. Is that normal or is my command wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fusermount -u ~/plaintext` only affects `~/plaintext/`. Seeing *encrypted* files (i.e. files with "strange" names and content) in `~/secret/` before or after `fusermount -u` is normal.

Now if you want to get access to the plain files again, you run `encfs ~/secret ~/plaintext` again. Keep in mind `encfs` works on file level. The tool needs to "see" encrypted files to decrypt them, so there they are waiting for `encfs` to work on them again.

However if `~/secret` is also a mountpoint (e.g. your external drive is mounted there), then it's probably not mounted with `encfs` (or at least it shouldn't be). Unmounting it, if this is what you want, is not the job for `encfs`.